# How to manage to serve media files with Django, Nginx, Docker and Traefik?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to upload and persist media files (images, pdfs) in an application with Django. 
It's working fine in development mode, but I'm getting a "404 Not Found The requested URL /mediafiles/images/test.jpg was not found on this server." when deployed on a server.

"Funny" thing to note : I manage to upload files, I see them on my host, and both containers (nginx and webserver), but whenever I try to access them I get the Not Found error.

I've read and tries many things without success such as modifying the nginx conf file, playing with the docker-compose file.. would you have any idea where I should look from now on?

Here's what I think are pertinent informations :

Server : Ubuntu 16.04

#### Docker-Compose

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      - ./mediafiles:/usr/share/nginx/mediafiles:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=${TRAEFIK_HOST}_static"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}; PathPrefixStrip: /static/"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"

  webserver:
    image: ${MY_IMAGE}
    volumes:
      - ./static:/tmp/html/static
      - ./mediafiles:/code/server/mediafiles
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=${TRAEFIK_HOST}"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=8000"

volumes:
  mediafiles:
```

#### Nginx Config

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location /mediafiles {
    autoindex on;
    alias /usr/share/nginx/mediafiles/;
}
}
```

#### Django Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/code/server/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/tmp/html/static/'
```

#### Django urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT,)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Tell me if there's other information needed. And thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that `mediafiles` location comes before root one

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /mediafiles {
        autoindex on;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/mediafiles/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```